# Athena - Convert String based timestamp to ISO time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have a timestamp column that has a value like this `Fri, 12 Mar 2021 14:00:02:270`

I want to convert it to timestamp format to use any timestamp-related functions.

Expected output:

`2021-03-12 14:00:02`

I tried this, but seems its not the right syntax.

`cast(date_parse(recordtime,'%a, %d %b %Y %T:%i:%S:')as TIMESTAMP )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html), the error seems to be at the end of the query, because `%T` is the format `Time, 24-hour (hh:mm:ss)`, so you don't need to specify `%i` and `%S` after that.

This one works:

```
SELECT cast(date_parse('Fri, 12 Mar 2021 14:00:02:270', '%a, %d %b %Y %T:%f') as timestamp)
```

You have to add `%f` at the end to handle the millisecond after your Time format.